# Asynchronous initialization of Redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, reducers

I'm really uncertain how to handle a multi-part, asynchronous initialization process in a redux application. I need to load a bunch of data asynchronously. Only after each piece of data has completed loading can the application be considered "ready". I am really unsure how this is supposed to be done in redux.

Let's say an application needs three things to be completed before it is considered `ready`. These preconditions are:

1. `theme` has retrieved its definition from a local file;
2. `userPrefs` has retrieved its settings from local storage; and
3. `api` has confirmed that a certain remote server is reachable.

On the one hand, it seems like I can simply add another reducer (`app`?) that listens for the actions from these three components. When it has heard from all three, the app is "ready". This seems to be the idea behind [the advice here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/316#issuecomment-124485087).

Alternatively, I can probably derive the data at the consumer. This lookup will probably happen a lot, but I suppose it could be memoized (though it still seems wasteful).

Lastly, I can see myself writing my own `combineReducers` so that the root reducer has a separate, "top level" branch of the state tree (this just seems like a variation of the first option) or write it so that one reducer has access to the entire state tree.

I think I can write the rest of the application without any cross-cutting concerns, but this doesn't seem to be an unusual situation. How am I supposed to approach this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method to fire off the three action creators which will in turn kick the actions to propagate state changes by the reducers.

This component lifecycle method will make sure that your state tree is ready. Simple as that.

Also, make sure to put the action creators in the top level / parent component, probably `App.js` since you want to bootstrap these states when the application loads.

I normally separate the reducers into different files - each file denoting a particular state tree. For example, I like to separate authentication related reducers from UI related reducers, and so on. Then you need to use `combineReducers` as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for this. This sounds maybe like my second option (derive the "ready" condition at the consumer). Would you trigger a final action creator to store the "ready" info in the state tree, or continually check this condition in the `App` component (maybe via a selector), or keep the "ready" information in the `App` component's local state?

Comment: If you use the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method, whenever the state changes, the component will re-render automatically. I like using a ternary operator to check if the state is ready. Example: `{!!this.props.myState
                ? this.props.myState.name
                : ""}`

Answer (score 2):

I've accepted the answer by James J. above, because he took the time to give a completely valid answer and I think his is a great solution. I thought I should include the solution I ended up going with as well, though. There is no one correct answer, but I don't like the idea of putting any business logic in a view layer (it just feels like it should not be there and redux offers other alternatives).

First, here is a boring, top-level, connected component. The only things to notice are the `initializeApplication()` method prop that is exposed through `operators`, and the `ready` state prop (available through the `state.application` coming from redux.

```
// components/Application.js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { operators, selectors } from './store'; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars


class Application extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.initializeApplication();
    }
    render() {
        return <div>Application ready? { this.props.application.ready }</div>;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    application: state.application,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = ({
    initializeApplication: operators.initializeApplication,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Application);
```

And here is the redux part of the application. It uses [a variation of the ducks](https://www.robinwieruch.de/the-soundcloud-client-in-react-redux-ducks/) structure. In ducks, all actions are exposed through "operators" (basically, types are wrapped by actions, which are wrapped by action creators, which are wrapped by operators).

```
// store/Application/index.js
import { createReducer } from '../../Utils';
import { operators as UserPrefs } from '../UserPrefs';
import { operators as Api } from '../Api';


// TYPES:
const types = {
    INITIALIZED: 'Application/initialized'
};

// ACTION CREATORS:
const actions = {
    initialized: () => ({ type: INITIALIZED })
};

// OPERATORS:
const initializeApplication = () => dispatch =>
    Promise.all([
        dispatch(UserPrefs.initializeUserPrefs()),
        dispatch(Api.initializeApi())
    ])
    .then(() => dispatch(actions.initialized()));

const operators = {
    initializeApplication
};

// REDUCER:
const initialShape = {
    ready: false
};
const reducer = createReducer(initialShape)({
    [INITIALIZED]: (state) => ({...state, ready: true })
});

// EXPORTS
export default reducer;

export {
    operators,
    types
};
```

Obviously, the operators being called here must return promises that resolve only after they are done running. For example:

```
// store/UserPrefs/index.js
// ** NOT INCLUDING REDUCERS, TYPES, ETC **
const initializeUserPrefs = () => dispatch =>
    Promise.all([
        loadDefaultPrefs(),
        loadCurrentPrefs()
    ])
    .then(
        ([
            defaultPrefs,
            currentPrefs
        ]) => dispatch(actions.initialized(defaultPrefs, currentPrefs))
    );

const operators = {
    initializeInventory
};

export {
    operators
};
```

The only controversial thing here is that some of these ducks-style reducer modules necessarily "know" about other ducks (`application` knows about `userPrefs` and `api`) and dispatches its operators directly, introducing a tight binding, but since redux allows for hierarchical reducer trees, I don't think this is a game-breaker, but I can see why some won't like this solution either.

Comment: Andrew, consider using an `IS_FETCHING` reducer as well that will show a spinner.

Comment: Yep. Thanks. The code here is just hypothetical. My actual initialization process should take a tiny fraction of a second since it is loading local data assets, either from local storage or from a local file bundle. It typically should finish (and resolving or failing) in less than one animation frame.